# CKAN - Scalability

Tags: scalability, datastore, ckan

There isn't much information about scalability of the CKAN instance or in general details about it's architecture in it's documentation. It mentions though that SOLR is used for indexing but how to increase performance when you have a very large resource in datastore (GB). Is it horizontal scaling that's recommeneded? How? or how SOLR search indexes could be improved? Any ideas by the one's using CKAN.

Comment: What's the specific bottleneck? Is it that the datastore query is intensive or are you trying to return a particularly large quantity of data? You could use top to see whether the load is on postgres or python/ckan.

Comment: I have a large resource and I am using datastore_search with filters (only one filter), the response is quite slow so I am wondering is it SOLR that indexes for datastore_search?

Comment: It's postgres with a thin python wrapper. Did you try using top to see where the bottleneck? Otherwise, I wonder if you could use 'paster --plugin=ckan profile' to help.

Comment: As said didn't find any documentation about how SOLR is used by CKAN? According to solr "Solr is a standalone enterprise search server with a REST-like API. You put documents in it (called "indexing") via JSON, XML, CSV or binary over HTTP. You query it via HTTP GET and receive JSON, XML, CSV or binary results." - How to make use of SOLR features? Shouldn't be relevant to how this information in CKAN documentation?

Comment: The documents in CKAN's SOLR are the data search results. However the scaling you asked the question about is about the data in the datastore which is Postgres.